# Designing java client

Tags: java, client

I'm currently developing a client/server application in Java and i can't make up my mind on how to design the client.

At the moment i have a server that can accept multiple connections and every connection has a loop listening for commands and respond to them. The server looks like this:

```
    try{

        mIn = new DataInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());
        mOut = new DataOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());

        while(true){

            byte tPackType = mIn.readByte();

            switch(tPackType){

                case PackType.LOGIN:
                    login();
                    break;
                case PackType.REGISTER:
                    register();
                    break;
                default:

            }

        }

    }catch (IOException e){
        mLog.logp(Level.WARNING, this.getClass().getName(), "run()", "IOException in run()", e);
    }finally{
        try{
            mOut.close();
            mIn.close();
            mSocket.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now, the client is basically just a number of methods sending a request to the server and returns the response. I want to be able to receive updates from the server. 
I would appreciate any suggestions on reading that can help me find a solution.
Is there any patterns i could look into?

Thank you in advance, veLr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I want to be able to receive updates from the server`

I think that you have two options to do this.

- Option 1 is to make your client poll the server for updates. I would not recommend this since this will eventually increase your load on your server. You will most likely have performance issue the moment you attempt to scale your system up.
- Option 2 is to create a small server on your client. So basically, whenever there is an update, the server would connect to the client and send it the updates. I would recommend this procedure since it allows you to establish connections between your server and clients only when needed. The problem, when opposed to the previous method, is that you will need to track of the ports and IP's of your clients. You could implement a `HashTable` with Client ID's as keys and their connection properties as their keys. Once you have an update, you will look up the client in the HashTable, obtain the connection information, connect and send the information.

The server on the client side will then get the data and do whatever you want the client to do once an update is received.

Comment: Option 3 is that the client connects to the server, but then waits for the server to send updates through the connection.  That avoids polling, but also avoids having the server initiate a connection back to the client, which tends to cause problems when firewalls are involved.  (Plus it's weird.)

Comment: @Wyzard: If I am understanding you correctly, you want the client to open a port on the server and leave it open without doing anything?

Comment: Open a *connection*, but yes.  ("Open a port" means either to listen for incoming connections, or to configure a firewall to allow connections through.)  The client initiates the connection because the it knows the server's address and the server shouldn't have to know all the clients' addresses.  But once connected, the server knows when updates need to be sent, and the client doesn't.  So the server initiates the updates.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers! Option 1 is what I'm trying to avoid but option 2 and 3 sounds somewhat like what i am looking for. So basically I need to have two connections, one where the client sends requests to the server and one where the client receives updates from the server? I was thinking in the terms of only having one connection open but i guess it's impossible.

Comment: @Wyzard: Hmm I see. But wouldn't that cause (server) resources to be used while the client is waiting?

Comment: The "server" is a pool of resource intended to serve and is always assumed that it will have enough resources to be used :-) In reality, it is not practical to run a server at client side . The work that will be required by the server to establish connection to all its client backwards is a big no-no when the number of clients increases. Usually the connection is kept alive till the client logs out and all communication is done through it (except file transfers if any). And if this was a real case scenario then veLr would be using java "nio" and "selector based socket multiplexing".

Comment: He still can think about using Apache MINA.

Comment: After googeling java.nio and "selector based socket multiplexing" i have come to the conclusion that i need to look deeper into this since i expect my server to be able to handle thousands of connections.